How to run a pure assembler program from the flash of an STM32?
I am trying to write a pure assembler program (LED blink) for the Nucleo-F103RB.
I create a new project in the STM32CodeIDE and remove all files except STM32F103RBTX_FLASH.ld and startup_stm32f103rbtx.s
Then I change in the STM32F103RBTX_FLASH.ld next string...
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(my_init)

...and write in the startup_stm32f103rbtx.s next code...
  .syntax unified
  .cpu cortex-m3
  .thumb
  
  .equ  PERIPH_BASE,                        0x40000000
  
  .equ  APB2PERIPH_BASE, (PERIPH_BASE     + 0x00010000)
  .equ  GPIOA_BASE,      (APB2PERIPH_BASE + 0x00000800)
  .equ  GPIOA_CRL,       (GPIOA_BASE      + 0x00000000) // 0dec shift
  .equ  GPIOA_ODR,       (GPIOA_BASE      + 0x0000000C) //12dec shift
  .equ  GPIO_PIN_5,      (0x00000001 <<  5)
  
  .equ  AHBPERIPH_BASE,  (PERIPH_BASE     + 0x00020000)
  .equ  RCC_BASE,        (AHBPERIPH_BASE  + 0x00001000)
  .equ  RCC_APB2ENR,     (RCC_BASE        + 0x00000018)
  
  .equ  RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN_Pos, (2U)
  .equ  RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN_Msk, (0x1UL << RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN_Pos)  /*!< 0x00000004 */
  .equ  RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN,      RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN_Msk            /*!< I/O port A clock enable */

  .macro WAIT_500
    mov R1, #500
    loop1_\@:
      mov R2, #1000
      loop2_\@:
        subs R2, #1
        bne loop2_\@
      subs R1, #1
      bne loop1_\@
  .endm
  
  .macro LED_ON
    ldr R1, =GPIOA_ODR
    ldr R3, =GPIO_PIN_5
    str R3, [R1]
  .endm
  
  .macro LED_OFF
    ldr R1, =GPIOA_ODR
    ldr R3, =0x00000000
    str R3, [R1]
  .endm
  
    .section .text.my_init
    .weak my_init
    .type my_init, %function
  
  my_init:
    WAIT_500
  
    ldr R1, =RCC_APB2ENR
    ldr R2, =RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN
    ldr R3, [R1]
    orr R3, R2
    str R3, [R1]
  
    ldr R1, =GPIOA_CRL
    ldr R3, =0x00300000
    str R3, [R1]
  
  loop:
    LED_ON
    WAIT_500
    LED_OFF
    WAIT_500
  b loop
  
  .size my_init, .-my_init

This code does work, the LED blinks.
But only when I press Run or Debug in the STM32CodeIDE. If I press the reset button or reconnect the board the LED will not blinks.
What shall I do to run this program from flash after MCU hardware reset?

Have you checked the option bytes?

@Jon What is the option bytes and where they are checked?

You need a vector table at the start of flash which must contain at the bare minimum 2 entries: the stack start address in RAM, and the reset vector (flash address of the start of your code). You'll find an example in one of the assembler .s files you removed from the project.

@brhans Well, I will try to reduce this table from the original startup_stm32f103rbtx.s. Thanks.

You can post it to the STM forum too.

As @brhans said, there is not the isr_vector in my example. So if I add next code:
.section .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
.word _estack
.word my_init

...the program will works well after hard reset.
